# How better a way to accomplish a button click inside of the very button click in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have this code where in the case that a user clicks a button an ajax call is made. If the ajax call fails, the button should somehow be reclicked. Have tried the code below but it doesn't seem to be working

```
$("#click_me").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
                type: "post",
                url: "me.php",
                dataType: "text",
                data: {
                       ......

                      },

                timeout: 20,
                tryCount : 0,
                retryLimit : 3,
                success: function(data){
                                              //do some awesome stuff
                                       },
                error: function(xhr, textStatus){
                           if (textStatus == 'timeout') {
                            this.tryCount++;
                            if (this.tryCount <= this.retryLimit) {
                                //try again
                                $.ajax(this);
                                return;
                            }
                            else{

                                     //You got no connection bro
                                     //retry by triggering the button click
                                     $("#click_me").trigger('click');
                                }

                  }


          });

});
```

Comment: have you set a break point on the line with `$("#click_me").trigger('click');`. If so, what is the value of `textStatus` and `tryCount`?

Comment: Why don't you just make a function that calls the Ajax and if it fails, call it again?

Comment: Also, this would continue to make that ajax request indefinitely. Why assume it will work the second time if it didn't the first?

Comment: So do it like `$("#click_me").click(callMeAjax);` then have the actual Ajax call in a function `callMeAjax` then  `//You got no connection bro
                                     callMeAjax();`

Comment: Not all browsers are friendly about simulating interactive events (like triggering clicks or link clicks) since that could be used very maliciously. Since you're just wanting to retrigger the function bound to the button click, just recall that (not anonymous) function rather than taking a user action that didn't actually occur.

Comment: Well, I would have wished that the calls be made until the user finds a connection. Would that be bad?

Comment: @RandyCasburn I haven't, but on it

Comment: that would possibly be an infinite loop

Comment: @Anthony Awesome suggestion, let me try it

Comment: btw, seems you miss one `}` in `error : function`

Comment: If they are timing out because they have no connection, you could check if they are online before sending the request (maybe even disable the button if they aren't online). There's an API for checking if the browser is online. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorOnLine/Online_and_offline_events

Comment: @Anthony's suggestion works like magic, thanks man!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a function that makes the ajax request, call it when the button is clicked. Also call it from within if the ajax fails.

```
function clickUntilDone {

    $.ajax({
           type: "post",
           url: "me.php",
           dataType: "text",
           data: {
                  ......

               },

           timeout: 20,
           tryCount : 0,
           retryLimit : 3,
           success: function(data){
                                         //do some awesome stuff
                                  },
           error: function(xhr, textStatus){
                    if (textStatus == 'timeout') {
                       this.tryCount++;
                       if (this.tryCount <= this.retryLimit) {
                             //try again
                            $.ajax(this);
                            return;
                        }
                        else{

                                 // ***** HERE --->
                                 clickUntilDone()
                            }

              }


      });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

For click, you can use

```
$("#click_me").click();
```

inside of click button event click button using jquery

```js
var i=0;
$("#click_me").click(function(){
  
   console.log("#click_me button click");
   i++;
   if(i < 4)
      $("#click_me").click();
   
});

$("#click_me").click();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" id="click_me">Click Me!</button>
```

Comment: I have tried it is working.Can you please check my coding?

Comment: Yeah the click inside of a click seems to be working, I guess I have bigger isssues than meets the eye

Comment: You can write some console.log in error function find out your problem.